# Annotating MS Word and PDF files in Haxe?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, text-editor, haxe

I am considering Haxe for a new project because I would like the application to be multi-platform. However, I searched for and did not find the libraries I would need. Is there a relatively easy way to display and annotate MS Word and PDF files in Haxe? Would I need to transcompile to C++ and then rely on third party MS tools and an SDK like Foxit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not any native Haxe solutions for importing and programmatically annotate MS Word or PDF files as far as I know. (Pretty sure about that.)
If you find native solutions for Haxe supported target languages (C++, Javascript/Node, C#, Java, Python or PHP...) you could write externs for those libraries, and this way make them work as a part of your Haxe solution.

Comment: Adding to Cambiata's answer, you can read more about extern classes in Haxe in the manual: https://haxe.org/manual/lf-externs.html

Answer (score 0):

PDF (only generic file structure and partial decryption)
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/format/tree/master/format/pdf